# How to make a bash script that will use cdhit on each file in the directory separately?

Tags: bash, sh, bioinformatics

I have a directory with >500 multifasta files. I want to use the same program (cd-hit-est) to cluster sequences in each of the files and then save the output in another directory. I want the name to be the same of the file to be the same as in the original file.

```
for file in /dir/*.fasta; 
do
echo "$file";
cd-hit-est -i $file -o /anotherdir/${file} -c 0.98 -n 9 -d 0 -M 120000 -T 32;
done
```

I get partial output and then an error:

```
...
^M# comparing sequences from      33876  to      33910
    .................---------- new table with       34 representatives
    ^M# comparing sequences from      33910  to      33943
    .................---------- new table with       33 representatives
    ^M# comparing sequences from      33943  to      33975
    ................---------- new table with       32 representatives
    ^M# comparing sequences from      33975  to      34006
    ................---------- new table with       31 representatives
    ^M# comparing sequences from      34006  to      34036
    ...............---------- new table with       30 representatives
    ^M# comparing sequences from      34036  to      34066
    ...............---------- new table with       30 representatives
    ^M# comparing sequences from      34066  to      35059
    .....................
    Fatal Error:
    file opening failed
    Program halted !!

    ---------- new table with      993 representatives

        35059  finished      34719  clusters
```

No output file was produced. Could anyone help me understand where do I make a mistake?

Comment: You should quote `$file` everywhere you use it: `cd-hit-est -i "$file" -o /anotherdir/"$file"`. Does your command work for a single file? Where is the filename from your `echo` in the example output?

Comment: The `^M`s look like you have allowed Windows near your data as Linux/Unix uses linefeeds rather than carriage returns.

Comment: Also, look at GNU Parallel to speed up and simplify this kind of thing https://www.biostars.org/p/63816/

Comment: @BenjaminW. thank you for your response, so I did put all $file into '$file' and I run a test for a directory that had just one file, and I got exactly the same 'fatal error'... I don't really understand what could be the cause, because when I run the same program. But, if I run the program itself (the line with cd-hit-est) on 1 file that is specified by name then everything works perfectly. This means that I am doing sth wrong within the loop?

Comment: Hi @MarkSetchell, thank you for your comments. I am not sure about `^M`because, there is no Windows os anywhere nearby, I can't actually see it in my terminal :) Thanks for a link to biostars!

Comment: If you look at the very beginning of your output, what do you see for the `echo "$file"` line? Also, make sure you use double quotes, and not single quotes as in your comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, it seems that I have an answer now, in any case if somebody is looking for a similar answer.

```
for file in /dir/*.fasta; 
        do
                echo "$file";
                cd-hit-est -i "$file" -o /anotherdir/$(basename "$transcriptome") -c 0.98 -n 9 -d 0 -M 120000 -T 32;
        done
```

Calling the output file in another way did the trick.

Answer (score 2):

```
doit() {
    file="$1"
    echo "$file";
    cd-hit-est -i "$file" -o /anotherdir/$(basename "$transcriptome") -c 0.98 -n 9 -d 0 -M 120000 -T 32;
}
env_parallel doit ::: /dir/*.fasta
```